# select a specific value in a group by statement using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

for instance i have this table

prices

```
    price   |   location
------------+-------------
 2.50       | U express
 2.19       | Carrefour
```

if I request

```
SELECT avg(price), min(price), max(price) FROM prices GROUP BY price;
```

I will get

```
  avg   |  min  |  max  
--------+-------+-------
2.34500 | 2.19  | 2.50
```

Is it possible to get the following result using only one sql statement ?

```
  avg   |  min  |  max  |  minLocation  | maxLocation
--------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------
2.34500 | 2.19  | 2.50  | Carrefour     |  U express
```

**minLocation** is the value in the "location" column for which the price is the lowest. And **maxLocation**, for which the price is the highest.

Comment: Add some more sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways.  One method is to use a subquery:

```
select avg(price), min(price), max(price),
       max(case when seqnum_a = 1 then location end) as min_location,
       max(case when seqnum_d = 1 then location end) as max_location
from (select p.*, row_number() over (order by price desc) as seqnum_d,
             row_number() over (order by price asc) as seqnum_a
      from prices p
     ) p;
```

This is just one solution.  Postgres offers arrays, a wealth of window functions, and the `filter` clause (which is a bit faster) that offer other solutions as well.  The above is standard SQL and reasonable.

Comment: thanks, why do you use the *max()* function in the first *select* statement ?

Comment: @ballangddang . . . `MAX()` and `MIN()` return the same value.  There is only one value that matches the condition.